# Jenkins: Execute AWS CLI command inside a pipeline Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, aws-cli

Do you know how to execute AWS CLI command inside a `Jenkinsfile` in order to build a pipeline? I didn't find any plugins

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you need install aws cli on your server and make sure the jenkins user has permissions to run it.

Or simply use the Amazon AMI when creating the EC2 instance, it comes with the aws cli.

Assign a role the instance with the appropriate policy. ( it is simpler that using user key in aws configure )

Within your pipeline steps use `sh 'aws ...'`

Comment: any idea how we can run aws cli in jenkins if jenkins is running inside docker? I have posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777166/unable-to-run-kubectl-inside-dockerized-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install AWS CLI in Jenkins instance in order to perform calls to your environment.

To setup it you need to create a new user to Jenkins in AWS and configure properly the keys. Take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-jenkins.html

After that you can do calls inside your Jenkins jobs using 'Shell commands' to AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups
```

If you are using Ansible as your automation tool, take a look here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/